# How do I force IE to open a new Browser on custom hotkey?

Tags: internet-explorer, command-line

I'm using AutoHotKey which is a program that lets me define my own hot keys.  I have a hot key to open a link in IE. When I run the hot key command again the same window opens in the same browswer.  I would like it to open in a new browser.

I'm using "Run www.google.com", for example.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, hopefully the superuser folks have a solution for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it:

iexplore.exe -noframemerging www.google.com

Answer (score 0):

Try
explorer http://www.google.com

Comment: no go.  I'm pretty sure that its the same as e www.google.com

Comment: I tested it on my system before I posted it.  Maybe your explorer is configured to not open stuff in a new window?  In which case, why override user preferences?

Comment: I have multi desktops setup and if I have IE open in a different desktop the page opens in that desktop and I can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Which IE?

iexplore -nomerge http://example.com

Will typically work for IE8.

Comment: Both of these do the same thing. What does "didn't work" mean? Are you using IE8?

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> Internet Options -> [Tabs] Settings -> Open links from other programs in: [Select] A new window.

Comment: I saw this, but I want IE to work the same generally except when I use the hot key.  Thanks though